# Icon Naming Specification as Second Option

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

If my memory is not deceiving me, I read somewhere that you can use the system icons (Icon Naming) as second option if the "primary" is not available. In other words, we can choose an icon that is in a directory any and if it is not available a system icon (Icon Naming Specification) is used.

This is possible or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

No, although you can implement that logic yourself in your code.

What you may have read is that you can install a separate icon theme using the Icon Naming Spec names, and applications will fall back to the default `hicolor` icon theme in the case where your icon theme is missing an icon?